# What is a name for a unit of measure and value

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm trying to find a word that describes both the unit and value of something. The unit types and values are arbitrary.

For instance "10 meters" and "52 inches" are examples of (the word). "10 liters" and "40 watts" are examples of (the word), etc.

Is there such a word? I can't think of it.

Comment: To note, (I'm a coder) I was looking for a good variable name to describe a JavaScript object that holds the value and units of some CSS styles. Padding, width, height all can be expressed in px, %, em, etc. I'm adding these *measurements* together in a way that only like units of measure can be added to each other. So in this way each dimension has a *measurement* but not all measurements are compatible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would think the word *quantity* might suffice, but the dictionary strongly supports the word ***measurement***. From [Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/measurement):

> *the exact size, degree, strength etc of something, usually expressed in numbers of standard units*

So, "10 liters" is a measurement. So are "40 watts," "12 acres," and "7.5 light years."

Comment: Seems reasonable that this is correct though I wasn't sure at first. I read up a bit more on *measurement* and it seems to be a good fit for the word I had in mind. The Wikipedia article solidified it for me: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measurement

Answer (score 3):

The term  *dimensioned quantity* or  *dimensioned number* denotes numbers with units attached ([1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensionless_quantity),[2](http://www.trinidadstate.edu/mathsci/physics/common/ufa.htm),[3](http://www.chacocanyon.com/smm/readings/dimensions.shtml)). (Note: link 3 may popup an ad.)

Link 1 (a [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensionless_quantity) article) uses the circumlocution *non-dimensionless quantity* rather than the more-direct term *dimensioned quantity*, because the article primarily discusses dimensionless quantities rather than dimensioned ones.

Link 2 (a [trinidadstate.edu](http://www.trinidadstate.edu/mathsci/physics/common/ufa.htm) webpage) says “Dimensioned numbers follow a few simple rules” and then explains several conversion, addition, and multiplication rules for dimensioned numbers.

Link 3 (apparently an [online course](http://www.chacocanyon.com/smm/readings/dimensions.shtml) reading) says:

> A “dimensioned quantity”  is a number with attached units. For example, your age is a dimensioned quantity — 29 years, say. [...] Whenever we perform arithmetic with dimensioned quantities, the units must be consistent and make sense. You can use this fact to figure out what gets multiplied by what. But to do that, you have to understand the rules of arithmetic with dimensioned quantities.
>
> Dimensioned quantities always have two parts: the numeric part, and the unit part. The “unit” is the dimension — years or seconds in the examples above. Dimensioned quantities obey the rules of arithmetic, with a couple of modifications: [...]

Comment: You've done a good job of answering this question from a mathematical (or scientific) perspective; my answer was more from a conversational perspective (I wouldn't expect to hear anyone say "dimensioned quantity" at the bus stop, e.g. – not unless I was at a convention with a bunch of physicists, or watching _The Big Bang Theory_). (Lest I be misunderstood; I'm not criticizing your answer, I'm complimenting [sic?] it.)